# No qualifying bean of type available (Spring Data)

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, dependencies, spring-data-jpa

I'm getting this error when I try to autowire interface that extends CrudRepository. I have two hibernate xml configs for 2 databases. The full stack is

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'helloController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'stockService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.publishing.test.stock.services.StockService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)

```
<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url"></property>
    <property name="connection.username"></property>
    <property name="connection.password"></property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
     <property name="connection.pool_size">100</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
    <!--<property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>-->

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop the existing table and create new one -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <property name="packagesToScan">com.publishing</property>

    <!-- Mention here all the model classes -->
    <mapping class="com.publishing.models.Stock"/>

</session-factory>
```

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {


@Autowired
private StockService stockService;
```

I have 3 lines also in Spring Config

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.publishing" />
<context:annotation-config />
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.publishing" />
```

Service is

```
@Service("StockService")
public interface StockService extends CrudRepository<Stock, Long> {
```

**Edit:**

Ok, now we have edited hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    <!-- Drop the existing table and create new one -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <!--<property name="packagesToScan">com.publishing</property>-->

    <!-- Mention here all the model classes -->
    <mapping class="com.publishing.models.Stock"/>
```

And service

```
@Service("stockService")
public interface StockService extends CrudRepository<Stock, Long> {
```

[image]

Comment: This is caused by the fact that your bean/service should be named exactly the same as the instance in the controller, it's case sensitive.

Comment: I did it, still a same error

Comment: Can you please show the scan package configuration in your project?

Comment: Now it says "Couldn't autowire There is more than one bean of StockService type"

Scan package?! You mean this?!  <context:component-scan base-package="com.publishing" />

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. And that's the package where are located your services, I hope?

Comment: Yes, com.publishing.test.stock.services there is

Comment: This exception is saying that the bean is defined twice, why are using both `<context:component-scan base-package="com.publishing" />` and `<property name="packagesToScan">com.publishing</property>` it might be the cause of the problem, because package are scanned twice, so the bean is defined twice.

Comment: It's because I was trying to find the solution and I added a same line in hibernate.cfg.xml also. I removed it and still doesn't work.

Comment: No you don't need the one in hibernate configuration. But can you please update the question with the new Exception and how have you edited the code?

Comment: Yes, I mean I removed it again. I understand your idea. I have edited it

Comment: Why have you removed the name in the bean definition? In the `@Service` annotation? It should be `@Service("stockService")`.

Comment: Because it says "Couldn't autowire There is more than one bean of StockService type"

Comment: Well this will lead you to the same first problem, and please add edited codes as updates to the question and not just override it.

Comment: I think it's a build problem. Make sure to clean your project and rebuild it so it takes into account the new changes.

Comment: No, it's still there

Answer (score 5):

This is caused by the fact that you defined the bean as `StockService` and you are referring to it as `stockService`, this should be the same name, case sensitive in both the service and the controller.

So the bean definition should be updated from:

```
@Service("StockService")
```

To :

```
@Service("stockService")
```

Because you are referring to it with `stockService`, in the controller in:

```
@Autowired
private StockService stockService;
```

**Note:**

Also make sure that your bean is defined in the scanned packages of spring.

Comment: I might be wrong but I thought with no `@Qualifier` specified Spring should try to autowire the StockService by type and the name should not matter.

Comment: @LazerBass actually, it will be autowired by the name specified in the `@Sevice` level, this is the same as iiving `@Qualifier`.

Comment: @LazerBass Glad it helps, you can check [**this article**](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/02/spring-bean-names.html) to find out more about it, it's quite interesting.

Comment: I did it only with hibernate config inside spring-root.xml by configuring hibernate properties inside beans. So could we make it works with hibernate.cfg.xml only?!

Comment: @Nesquik27 In that case, it's another thing that I can't help with, I am sorry, it's out of my knowledge.